# faccessat and AT_* defines are undefined

Tags: c, clang, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
// SYSTEM INCLUDE FILES
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>

// C STANDARD LIBRARY INCLUDE FILES
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *source = "file1.txt";
    char *dest = "file2.txt";

    printf("%d\n", faccessat(AT_FDCWD, source, F_OK | R_OK | W_OK, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW));
    printf("%d\n", faccessat(AT_FDCWD, dest, F_OK | R_OK | W_OK, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW));
    printf("Value of errno: %s\n", strerror(errno));

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this code with clang 14 and the command `clang -lrt -pthread -I/usr/include -std=c11 -o copy copy.c` I run into numerous issues:

```
copy.c:21:20: warning: implicit declaration of function 'faccessat' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    printf("%d\n", faccessat(AT_FDCWD, source, F_OK | R_OK | W_OK, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW));
                   ^
copy.c:21:30: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AT_FDCWD'
    printf("%d\n", faccessat(AT_FDCWD, source, F_OK | R_OK | W_OK, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW));
                             ^
copy.c:21:68: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW'
    printf("%d\n", faccessat(AT_FDCWD, source, F_OK | R_OK | W_OK, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW));
                                                                   ^
copy.c:22:30: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AT_FDCWD'
    printf("%d\n", faccessat(AT_FDCWD, dest, F_OK | R_OK | W_OK, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW));
                             ^
copy.c:22:66: error: use of undeclared identifier 'AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW'
    printf("%d\n", faccessat(AT_FDCWD, dest, F_OK | R_OK | W_OK, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW));
                                                                 ^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
```

The same code works on my Mac with MacOS 12, but does not work on Ubuntu in WSL. How would I fix this issue?

I tried to reinstall build-essentials, clang, gcc, glibc. I reviewed the header files and found that `fcntl.h` does not contain the AT_* definitions, yet the man page says they do. I was expecting the header file to contain the definitions.

Comment: I suspect that `faccessat()` (and `openat()`, `fstatat()`, *et al*) are all missing on Windows.

Comment: @andrew that shouldn’t matter on wsl

Comment: Do you have at least glib c 2.10?

Comment: @DanielA.White `faccessat()` (and the other `*at()` functions) all require support from inside the kernel to work.  I'd think that sure *could* matter when that kernel is Windows instead of Linux.

Comment: Wsl 2 does use the real Linux kernel

Comment: Did you define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L` as the man page instructed?

Comment: Use `-std=gnu11` instead to get library stuff beyond the C standard.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes I have glib c 2.35

Comment: @Haris The compiler defines _POSIC_C_SOURCE

Answer (score 0):

From what the comments have told me, and online, faccessat is a gnu extension in C, so to use it I would have to compile my code with -std=gnu11 to use these.

Comment: its a posix standard

Comment: You do not need `-std=gnu11`. You need to add `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` before any of your `#include` statements. See [the manual page](https://manned.org/faccessat.2)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli That macro is defined elsewhere and is already defined as that in my compiler